# Python & Ctypes: Passing a struct to a function as a pointer to get back data

Tags: python, pointers, struct, ctypes

I've looked through other answers but can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to call a function within a DLL for communicating with SMBus devices. This function takes a pointer to a struct, which has an array as one of it's fields. so...

In C:

```
typedef struct _SMB_REQUEST
{
    unsigned char Address;
    unsigned char Command;
    unsigned char BlockLength;
    unsigned char Data[SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE];
} SMB_REQUEST;
```

I think I have to set values for the Address, Command and BlockLength while the DLL fills the Data array.
The function that requires this struct takes it as a pointer

```
SMBUS_API int SmBusReadByte( SMBUS_HANDLE handle, SMB_REQUEST *request );
```

So I've set up the struct in Python like so:

```
class SMB_REQUEST(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Address", c_char),
            ("Command", c_char),
            ("BlockLength", c_char),
            ("Data", type(create_string_buffer(SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE))]
```

*Note: I've also tried ctypes.c_char*SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE for the data type*

To pass a pointer to a struct of this type to the function I have tried to initialise it first as follows:

```
data = create_string_buffer(SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE)
smb_request = SMB_REQUEST('\x53', \x00', 1, data)
```

This responds with:

```
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, c_char_Array_32 found
```

If I try leaving out the data array, like so:

```
smb_request = SMB_REQUEST('\x53', \x00', 1)
```

No, error.
However, then when I try to pass this to the function:

```
int_response =  smbus_read_byte(smbus_handle, smb_request))
```

I get:

```
ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_SMB_REQUES
T instance instead of SMB_REQUEST
```

I've tried passing it as a pointer:

```
int_response =  smbus_read_byte(smbus_handle, ctypes.POINTER(smb_request))
```

and I get:

```
----> 1
      2
      3
      4
      5

TypeError: must be a ctypes type
```

Here's how I've set up the art types:

```
smbus_read_byte.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(SMB_REQUEST))
```

I've tried casting but still no go. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

**Update:**

If I first initialise the struct like so:

```
smb_request = SMB_REQUEST('\xA6', '\x00', chr(1), 'a test string')
```

and then bass by reference:

```
int_response =  smbus_receive_byte(smbus_handle, ctypes.byref(smb_request))
```

I get no error. However, the function returns -1 when it should return '0' for success and non-zero for a fail. Checking the value of smb_request.Data gives back 'a test string' so no change there.
Any suggestions as to what might be going on here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Since I've gotten a couple of enquiries about whether my handle is correct, here's how I'm using it. The header file for the DLL declares the following:

```
typedef void *SMBUS_HANDLE;

//
// This function call initializes the SMBus, opens the driver and 
// allocates the resources associated with the SMBus.
// All SMBus API calls are valid 
// after making this call except to re-open the SMBus.
//
SMBUS_API SMBUS_HANDLE OpenSmbus(void);
```

So here's how I'm doing this in python:

```
smbus_handle = c_void_p() # NOTE: I have also tried it without this line but same result

open_smbus = CDLL('smbus.dll').OpenSmbus
smbus_handle =  open_smbus()
print 'SMBUS_API SMBUS_HANDLE OpenSmbus(void): ' + str(smbus_handle)
```

I call this before making the call to smbus_read_byte(). I have tried to set `open_smbus.restype = c_void_p()` but I get an error: `TypeError: restype must be a type, a callable, or None`

Comment: Hi Mark/Adam, Sorry for the delay in replying to your helpful answers. I finally got hold of a logic analyser and could see that the DLL was not behaving as expected. I now have the code working with the help you guys have given me. I'm pretty new to SO and I know that it's rude to leave a correct answer unchecked but I would like to mark both of your answers as being correct since you both put a lot of effort into helping me and your code now works. I can only seem to mark one answer as correct. What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Hey no problem.  Glad you figured it out.  You can only vote for one unfortunately.  It's your call.  You can always upvote both, too ;^)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's a working example.  It looks like you are passing the wrong type to the function.

#### Test DLL Code ("cl /W4 /LD x.c" on Windows)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SMBUS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#define SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE 5

typedef void* SMBUS_HANDLE;

typedef struct _SMB_REQUEST
{
    unsigned char Address;
    unsigned char Command;
    unsigned char BlockLength;
    unsigned char Data[SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE];
} SMB_REQUEST;

SMBUS_API int SmBusReadByte(SMBUS_HANDLE handle,SMB_REQUEST *request)
{
    unsigned char i;
    for(i = 0; i < request->BlockLength; i++)
        request->Data[i] = i;
    return request->BlockLength;
}

SMBUS_API SMBUS_HANDLE OpenSmbus(void)
{
    return (void*)0x12345678;
}
```

#### Python code

```
from ctypes import *
SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE = 5
ARRAY5 = c_ubyte * SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE

class SMB_REQUEST(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("Address", c_ubyte),
        ("Command", c_ubyte),
        ("BlockLength", c_ubyte),
        ("Data", ARRAY5)]

smbus_read_byte = CDLL('x').SmBusReadByte
smbus_read_byte.argtypes = [c_void_p,POINTER(SMB_REQUEST)]
smbus_read_byte.restype = c_int
open_smbus = CDLL('x').OpenSmbus
open_smbus.argtypes = []
open_smbus.restype = c_void_p

handle = open_smbus()
print 'handle = %08Xh' % handle

smb_request = SMB_REQUEST(1,2,5)

print 'returned =',smbus_read_byte(handle,byref(smb_request))
print 'Address =',smb_request.Address
print 'Command =',smb_request.Command
print 'BlockLength =',smb_request.BlockLength
for i,b in enumerate(smb_request.Data):
    print 'Data[%d] = %02Xh' % (i,b)
```

#### Output

```
handle = 12345678h
returned = 5
Address = 1
Command = 2
BlockLength = 5
Data[0] = 00h
Data[1] = 01h
Data[2] = 02h
Data[3] = 03h
Data[4] = 04h
```

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks to you also for putting in so much effort. It is very much appreciated! So trying what you have given me I get the same result (i.e. -1 returned from the function, and the ARRAY5() data elements stay unchanged. One thing I've noticed is that you are using c_int as the smb_handle type to be passed as the first argument to SmBusReadByte(). In the header file this is defined as: typedef void *SMBUS_HANDLE; That is why I was passing it as ctypes.c_void_p. Does that make a big difference here? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: p.s. My thinking was that the SmBusReadByte takes in the struct as a poninter and fills the data array with the returned data. To do this I thought I needed mutable memory for the Data array. That's why I was using create_string_buffer(SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE). I though mutable memory needed to be passed like this. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Sorry, my bad ... I'll correct it for a read.  I simulated a write.  If the function is returning -1, is your handle valid?

Comment: `Structures` are mutable.  `byref` passes a pointer to the structure, so the C code can modify it.  No need for create_string_buffer.

Comment: Also changed to `void*` for `SMB_HANDLE`, which is more correct for your situation.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've tried exactly what you have but still getting -1 as a return. I've added how I'm initialising the handle above. Am I using it ok? Thanks

Comment: I've updated above for OpenSmbus.  If you still get -1, check that your other parameters are correct (Address, Command, BlockLength).  Since it is a read, I doubt you have to initialize Data.

Comment: @Mark: Please see the comment I have put after my question above.

Comment: Best python CTypes tutorial ever.  Have you considered submitting it to the python docs?

Answer (score 7):

You're almost there.  You should use `c_char * SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE` as the type for the definition of `Data`.  This works for me on Mac OS X:

Shared library:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE 16

typedef struct _SMB_REQUEST
{
  unsigned char Address;
  unsigned char Command;
  unsigned char BlockLength;
  unsigned char Data[SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE];
} SMB_REQUEST;

int SmBusReadByte(void *handle, SMB_REQUEST *request)
{
  printf("SmBusReadByte: handle=%p request=[%d %d %d %s]\n", handle, 
      request->Address, request->Command, request->BlockLength, request->Data);
  return 13;
}

$ gcc test.c -fPIC -shared -o libtest.dylib
```

Python driver:

```
$ cat test.py
import ctypes

SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE = 16

class SMB_REQUEST(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Address", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("Command", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("BlockLength", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("Data", ctypes.c_char * SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE)]

libtest = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libtest.dylib')

req = SMB_REQUEST(1, 2, 3, 'test')

result = libtest.SmBusReadByte(ctypes.c_voidp(0x12345678), ctypes.byref(req))

print 'result: %d' % result

$ python test.py
SmBusReadByte: handle=0x12345678 request=[1 2 3 test]
result: 13
```

---

**UPDATE**

You're having problems because you need to set the result type of `open_smbus` to `void*`.  By default, ctypes assumes that functions return `int`s.  You need to say this:

```
open_smbus.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
```

You were getting an error because you were using `c_void_p()` (note the extra parentheses).  There's an important distinction between `c_void_p` and `c_void_p()`.  The former is a *type*, and the latter is an *instance* of a type.  `c_void_p` represents the C type `void*`, whereas `c_void_p()` represents an actual pointer instance (with a default value of 0).

Comment: Hi Adam, wow you went to a lot of effort there. Thanks very much. Unfortunately it fails with the following error: ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_SMB_REQUEST instance instead of pointer to SMB_REQUEST. Any idea what's going on there? Thanks

Comment: Im basically using the same as Mark and you have suggested but I've updated the above to include how I'm initialising he handle.

Comment: Please see the comment I have put after my question above

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
("Data", type(create_string_buffer(SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE))
```

to

```
("Data", (c_char * SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE)]
```

Comment: Hi Gabi, Thanks for your response. I tried that already in the above and got errors.