# Working with pointers to struct

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm working with python and import dll that have the following function:

```
int ReadMem(long Addr, long NumBytes, void* pData);
```

and I'm using this function to read memory from my target.

I want to create structure in python that is identical to structure defined in my target and then read it in python

I.E if i used C , i would wrote , 
ReadMem(0x10000000, 200, &mem_struct);

1. What is the best way to define the struct (ctype Structure class or struct)?
2. I used ctype Structure class:

```
class memory(Structure):

     fields_ = [("x", c_int),
               ("y", c_int)]
```

My question is: how can I call the ReadMem function with pointer to this struct? I try to use ctype pointer (I.E pi=pointer(memory) ) but I get TypeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across an answer for similar question in [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351721/python-ctypes-passing-a-struct-to-a-function-as-a-pointer-to-get-back-data)

and learn that i need to use the following code:

```
memory_ptr =  pointer(memory)
ReadMem(0x20000000, 100, memory_ptr)
```

Note : using byref(memory) probably works too