# Safearray in Python for Ctypes

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes, safearray

I was trying to use a function in DLL provided using Python Ctypes. I do know that writing a code in C++ would be more efficient and nice option. However, everything in my project is written in Python. So it would take a while for me to convert this code into C++.

The function that I would like to use from the DLL is something like this

```
int MLAPI_GetDeviceInfo(SAFEARRAY**, SAFEARRAY**)
```

As you know, ctypes does not have a data type called SAFEARRAY. So I was trying to make a Structure by Class and fields. (Actually there was someone who tried to make SAFEARRAY when I Googled, however, it did not work for me , also looked for similar cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351721/python-ctypes-passing-a-struct-to-a-function-as-a-pointer-to-get-back-data) )

```
from ctypes import *
class SAFEARRAYBOUND(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cElements" , c_ulong),
                ("lLbound" , c_long)]


class SAFEARRAY(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cDims", c_ushort),
                ("fFeatures", c_ushort),
                ("cbElements", c_ulong),
                ("cLocks", c_ulong),
                ("pvData", c_void_p),
                ("rgsabound", SAFEARRAYBOUND * 1)]
```

As the structure declaration says in the official document, I wrote two classes about [SAFEARRAY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-safearray) and [SAFEARRAYBOUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-safearraybound).

Then I wrote the code using ctypes for function use.

```
getdevicedata = Dll['MLAPI_GetDeviceInfo']
getdevicedata.restype = c_int
getdevicedata.argtypes = ()
getdevicedata()
```

I was quite unsure what to write for argtypes. Also, I am quite unsure what to put as arguments for getdevicedata function that I have wrote. These are pretty much of my code. I tried bunch of combinations for the arguments but everything failed. So I came to Stackoverflow for your answers...

I am quite noob to Stackoverflow and Python, so if I had made a mistake within this forum or code (or both) please let me know. Thanks for reading. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi, could you please share your code on how to access the MLAPI_GetDeviceInfo function? I am also trying to use the MSI mystic lights API to check for any compatible devices, but I could not get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your structures are correct (note they need more work since the arrays are of variable size), the `.argtypes` is:

```
getdevicedata.argtypes = POINTER(POINTER(SAFEARRAY)),POINTER(POINTER(SAFEARRAY))
```

Comment: Hi could you please elaborate on the "note they need more work since the arrays are of variable size"? I am facing the same question as OP but I still do not know how to solve it. Thanks